# Http requests sometimes get stuck or don't receive a response from the server on unstable network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, iis, mono

We are running a `.NET Core 2.2` `IIS` server and a `Unity 2018.4.2.f1` client. The client sends `GET` Http (not https) requests to the server using .net's `HttpClient`. Sometimes, the client does not receive a response from the server, and ends up hitting its timeout (even when the timeout is extremely long). However, on the server side it does show that the response was sent.

Another issue that may occur happens when sending a `POST` Http (not https) request with a few hundred kilobyte body. The "upload" may stall at any time, and also eventually hit a timeout.

The problems primarily occur when testing on a satelite network simulator, limited at `128 kilobit/s` and with a few % of packet duplication, reordering and loss. So basically, an extremely poor network (which is a requirement in our case). On our regular office network, it practically never occurs (perhaps once or twice months ago, I can't recall unfortunately).

We have tried polling Google's generate_204 page instead, and same problem occurs albeit much more rarely. We have tested the client on a `Windows` laptop as well as a `Linux` NUC. We have tried extending every timeout we could find (including removing Kestrel's `MinRequestBodyDataRate` and `MinResponseDataRate`), but nothing fixed it. However, we no longer suspect it to be a timeout because if we artificially slow down the POST upload to 4 kB/s on the client, we have seen succesful requests at 99% of the long client timeout. This opposed to the regular situation, where succesful POSTs would at most take about 40% of the timeout.

We have stripped down the client to a fresh Unity project with just the http request, still the occasional timeout. We have tried `UnityWebrequest` instead of `HttpClient`, same deal (which was expected as they probably use the same underlying `HttpWebRequest`).

So, does anyone know if this is some client/server settings that we can tweak? Or other ways to fix the issue? We are in a closed network, so we have some freedom for insecure fixes (hence why we use http for instance, to significantly reduce response times).

Comment: .NETCore 2.1 is stable, did you try this version instead?

Comment: @knocte No we did not. However, since the problem also occurred using Google's generate_204, we assume it is not related to the dotnet core version, and more likely is about some configuration somewhere.

Comment: anyway you shouldn't be using unstable versions of .NETCore

Answer (score 0):

I have battled a similar problem in my own Unity projects. Either the server was unstable or the internet connection from the user, leading to unexpected results. I fortunately structured my application so that all my webrequests go through the same pipeline, which makes handling such errors much more consistent.

I ended up with applying a retry on the connection if it had an internet connection, otherwise i would show a popup which would prompt the user to enable/ fix their internet connection. If they clicked the popup, the action that could not be completed would be re-invoked.

The following is what I use:

```
private const string _baseUrl = "your base url here";

private static IEnumerator CreatePostRequest(string url, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postParameters, Action<string> callback)
{
    if (!HasInternetConnection())
    {
        Action retryAction = () => CoroutineHandler.Handle(CreatePostRequest(url, postParameters, callback));

        // Show popup and attach the retry action as a callback to it
        yield break;
    }

    int tryCounts = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < tryCounts; i++)
    {
        string post_url = _baseUrl + url;
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        foreach (var parameter in postParameters)
        {
            form.AddField(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
        }

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(post_url, form);
        www.chunkedTransfer = false;
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.error == null && www.responseCode <= 200 && !www.downloadHandler.text.Contains("ERROR"))
        {
            var result = www.downloadHandler.text;
            callback?.Invoke(result);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Url: {0}, TryNumber: {1}, Parameters: {2}, Error: {3}, ResponseCode: {4}",
                _baseUrl + url,
                (i + 1).ToString(),
                "PARAMS: " + string.Join(" - ", postParameters.Select(x => x.Key + ": " + x.Value)),
                www.error,
                www.responseCode);

            // Your error logging class/ method here
            // MessageLogger.LogError(errorMessage);

            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.15f);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the same as our problem. The issue is that the request times out, while the server did receive it and tried to send a response.